# in jenkins svn checkout strategy, is it possible to update every day and emulate clean checkout on weekend?

Tags: svn, jenkins, svn-checkout

I am using jenkins with svn repository.
Usually I want only to update svn since cleaning is long and also might interrupt other processes running.
However in the weekend I want to do a clean checkout.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do is have a continuous integration job polling for changes every 10 minutes that is set to update and a nightly job that is polling for changes once a day that is set to checkout fresh each time.

I am not aware of any standard method to set up a job that updates normally, but checks out from scratch every  N hours/days/builds, but I can think of a workaround. Create a separate job that will wipe out workspace of the first and schedule it with the desired frequency. Just make sure the jobs don't run at the same time (there is an option for that somewhere).